# leanback library : How to draw focus for items in a VerticalGridView or HorizontalGridView?

Tags: android, android-tv, leanback

Im playing around the leanback library , i can see for most of the RowsFragment in the leanback package, they are using either HorizontalGridView or VerticalGridView, but when I create a new HorizontalGridView, is not drawing the focus, which means i cant use my remote control to scroll to that item.

Anyone know how to do that?

Also I can see some of the presenters they are using ItemBridgeAdapter for their VerticalGridView or HorizontalGridView, is it related to get the  focus of the views?

Comment: You mean you don't able to focus around the movies which is displayed.

Comment: have you got answer?

Comment: instead of creating a new widget, now i use Leanback library and create my customized row....

Comment: Can you share your implementation for HorizontalGridView focus and sroll on Android TV, Thanks

Comment: @Qing, You got the answer? If so, please share.

Comment: @Rakesh we end up giving up using our own recyclerview but using leanback library's rowfragment, you can just change hows the UI looks like for different row. Cause the rowfragment handles the animation already

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility that I can think of that's causing this is that you haven't set your custom view to be both `setFocusable(true)` and `setFocusableInTouchMode(true)`. You need these for whatever controls that you put into Leanback in order for the remote focus model to work.

You can do these in both code and xml; in xml via `android:focusable="true"` and `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` on the top level view that you want as your UI or card.